# How can I efficiently read entries in a directory?

Tags: directory, performance, system-calls, stat

I would like my program to efficiently detect if a file was added to a directory between two invocations. That analysis might block user input (this would be for the fish shell), so I want it to run as quickly as possible even with large directories.

I'm restricted to standard Unix, so I don't have access to inotify.

One way I thought to do this was to store the list of files of the watched dir in a hashset, and on analysis, to read through the entire dir and check if any entry is not in the hashset. Another would be to just lstat every single file and compare creation times.

Regardless, for my use case I need to do two things:

- **Call readdir for each entry.**
- **Call lstat for each entry.** (if I use the second solution)

My question is: **is there an efficient way to batch readdir and lstat?**

I *think* readdir isn't a syscall, but a wrapper around the SYS_getdents syscall, so presumably it does some buffering, but how much? How efficient is it?

And lstat wraps a single syscall AFAIK. Is there a more efficient version when you have a large number of files that you want to check simultaneously, and you don't want to pay the context switching call for each file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is another way - `getdents()`. It works virtually the same way as `readdir()` but it process several entries at a time. So you can allocate memory for an array of `linux_dirent` structures and `getdents()` will try to fill it.
This is not a POSIX function, so if you cannot use `inotify` (are you sure about that???), then it is possible you wont have access to `getdents()` too.
But ultimately, the `getdents()` does not differ from a manual loop of `readdir()` over similar array of `dirent` structures. The `getdents()` is not a wrapper over `readdir()` so it could be more efficient in comparison to a manual loop (and less bug-prone), but efficiency wont be mind-blowing.

If your goal is to just learn when a new file appears in the directory, or removed from it - you can `lstat()` the directory itself. The `mtime` of the directory is modified on file creation/deletion. Please note, the file modification belongs to the file itself and is not reflected in the directory's times.